# angular + tailwin css, style hot reload not working

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

I am currently trying to use angular + tailwind css.

Angular's hot reload can run successfully when the content changes (such as text or DOM elements).

But when I add an unused tailwind css class attribute, I must delete or annotate the following three `@import`, undo the annotation again or restore the deletion, and then save it, so that the new tailwind css class attribute can be displayed normally.

**@import "tailwindcss/base"**

**@import "tailwindcss/components"**

**@import "tailwindcss/utilities"**

I put these three `@import` in `app.component.scss`, and write dom elements in `app.component.html`.

**app.component.scss:**

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div class="border border-sky-500 underline">border</div>
```

**tailwind.config.js:**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.html", "./src/**/*.scss"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

This operation is quite inconvenient. Is there any setting in `tailwind.config.js` that I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable just-in-time mode, set the mode option to 'jit' in your `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
  // tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
   mode: 'jit',
    purge: [
      // ...
    ],
    theme: {
      // ...
    }
    // ...
  }
```

Since JIT mode generates your CSS on-demand by scanning your template files, it’s crucial that you configure the purge option in your tailwind.config.js file with all of your template paths, otherwise your CSS will be empty:

```
  // tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit',
   // These paths are just examples, customize them to match your project structure
   purge: [
     './public/**/*.html',
     './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}',
   ],
    theme: {
      // ...
    }
    // ...
  }
```

Now when you start your development server or build runner, Tailwind will generate your styles on-demand instead of generating everything in advance.

I would advise moving `@` imports to `src/styles.css`, then all components could use tailwind classes. But if you want to encapsulate and limit tailwind to one component then keep your imports as they are.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#enabling-jit-mode